# Devops Nuget versioning byBuildNumber does not work

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, nuget-package

I want the version numbers of the Nuget package to be incremented and human readable with every version pushed to the Artifacts store. This is my yaml.

```
variables:
  feedName :  'MyNugets'
  buildConfiguration: 'release'
  name:  $(Year:yyyy).$(Month).$(DayOfMonth).$(Rev:.r)

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Pack'
  inputs:
   command: pack
   versioningScheme: byBuildNumber

- task: NuGetAuthenticate@1
  displayName: 'NuGet Authenticate'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet push'
  inputs:
    command: push
    publishVstsFeed: '$(feedName)'
    allowPackageConflicts: true
```

Whatever suggestion I could find on SO or other google result. None of them seems to be working. I always get this error.

```
##[error]Could not find version number data in the following environment variable: BUILD_BUILDNUMBER. The value of the variable should contain a substring with the following formats: X.Y.Z or X.Y.Z.A where A, X, Y, and Z are positive integers.
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't store the name in a variable, put in in a separate section above `variables`.

```
name: $(Year:yyyy).$(Month).$(DayOfMonth)$(Rev:.r)

variables:
  feedName :  'MyNugets'
  buildConfiguration: 'release'
```

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: I'd perhaps have it with one less "period" before the Rev, so that it will be "2023.12.23.1" and not "2023.12.23..1"? So: "$(Year:yyyy).$(Month).$(DayOfMonth)$(Rev:.r). Or does the double period serve specific meaning as separator between date and revision, so it would be good to include?